# Trying to find the ImproperlyConfigured error in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-errors

I know this error has been asked a lot, but I read lots of posts, but I couldn't find the solution to my problem. Can anyone please help me identify where is my error?

It keeps appearing the following error:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'outside_world.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.`

outside_world\urls.py (the project's urls):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path(r'trip/', include("trip.urls")),
]
```

trip\urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

trip\views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)

def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

The tree of my project:
[Project Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSxCj.jpg)

When I remove `path(r'trip/', include("trip.urls")),` from outside_world\urls.py, it works perfectly, but I need to maintain this line.

Comment: path(r'trip/', include("trip.urls")), <-- This should go to project's urls.py

Answer (score 1):

Move these two urls to project's urls.py and out from outside_world\urls.py

```py
path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls)
path(r'trip/', include("trip.urls"))
```

Also you have an undefined index definition/class in the trip\views.py. That will cause errors if you go to http(s)://YourIP/YourProjectName/trip .. you should defined index.
It will work fine if you are typing, one of the below, since you have defined these views. Number is an integer (QuestionID) as you have defined

- http(s)://YourIP/YourProjectName/trip/Number or
- http(s)://YourIP/YourProjectName/trip/Number/results or
- http(s)://YourIP/YourProjectName/trip/Number/Vote since they are
  already defined.

Comment: Thank you, but the project is called **outside_world**, so `path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls)
path(r'trip/', include("trip.urls"))`, is already in project's urls. I already fixed the second thing you pointed out, and the error persists.

Comment: How come you have views in the project? Something is wrong? Will you edit the post and paste the tree of your project?

Comment: I was getting this error so I added a views.py file to my project's folder to see if I could at least open an url directly from the project's folder. I added my project's tree above so you can see it.

Comment: I guess then you may have to remove these two lines. "from . import views" and "    path(r'', views.detail, name='detail')," .. I don't see any other problem ..but this is my guess

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, but I removed those lines and still doesn't work. If nobody else answers this post I will restart the project from scratch.

Comment: Yes you can do that but before taking that last resort may be you want to rename the top url in trip/urls.py from index to something else and remove views from outside_world main project. Also wondering if there is a permanent redirect defined somewhere, connected to these paths.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I already restarted the project and so far the error has not appeared.